# I have two select queries combined using UNION. I am getting two results in one column how can I get it in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two select queries combined using UNION. I am getting two results in one column but I want to get it in two Columns

```
(SELECT count (*) As ServiceCreatedInOneMonth FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) and  CompanyID = 1 ) UNION ALL

(SELECT count (*) As ServiceCompletedInOneMonth FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND IsCompleted =1 and CompanyID = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT count (*) 
 FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] 
 WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
 AND CompanyID = 1 ) ServiceCreatedInOneMonth ,
(SELECT count (*) 
 FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient]
 WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
 AND IsCompleted =1 and CompanyID = 1) ServiceCompletedInOneMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify that into one single select query. Use `CASE WHEN` to check for `IsCompleted`

```
SELECT count (*) As ServiceCreatedInOneMonth,
       sum (case when IsCompleted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) As ServiceCompletedInOneMonth 
FROM   [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] 
WHERE  CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
and    CompanyID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add `null as ServiceCompletedInOneMonth` as the second column of your first query,
`null as ServiceCreatedInOneMonth` as the first column of your second query, then union. Note that parentheses are not needed with union:

```
    SELECT count (*) As ServiceCreatedInOneMonth,null as ServiceCompletedInOneMonth
    FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] 
    WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) and  CompanyID = 1 
UNION ALL
    SELECT null as ServiceCreatedInOneMonth,count (*) As ServiceCompletedInOneMonth 
    FROM [workAiderWinNe].[DynamicServiceDataOfClient] 
    WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND IsCompleted =1 and CompanyID = 1
```

Note:  I wrote this without checking the query. Squirrel's answer is best.